# Busca no Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Bom dia amigos, tenho a seguinte estrutura no firebase. Preciso fazer uma busca no meu banco, exibindo todos os produtos que estão na child Sem Barra, e também os supermercados e preço que estão salvos dentro de cada produto. Não encontrei nenhum metodo que me ajude a exibir todos os supermercados. Alguem poderia me ajudar?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Responder a sua pergunta corretamente me tomaria muito tempo, logo estarei respondendo de forma a lhe ajudar com o que você almeja. Eu costumo trabalhar com o firebase de forma mais padronizada possível e isso sempre me ajuda, exemplo esquemático:

```
achocolatado_1:
    estado: CE
    cidade: Fortaleza
    supermercado: Meu Supermercado
    ...

café_1:
    estado: RS
    cidade: Pelotas
    supermercado: Supermercado Compra Bem
    ...
```

e assim por diante.
Procure na documentação do Firebase como baixar dados em massa utilizando uma classe (objeto) com seus gets e sets, onde cada variável deverá ter exatamente o mesmo nome das chaves do Firebase.

Há um Listener **assíncrono** que observa se houve alguma alteração em seus dados e assim, sempre que altera-os, tudo será atualizado automaticamente. 
Logo, você poderá referenciar quais nós quiser e chamar quais dados quiser.
Eu também gosto de controlar os dados assíncronos salvando-os com o SharePreferences do Android e isso facilita muito a minha vida.

Não tem como lhe explicar com muitos detalhes pois é muita coisa, mas acredito ser um bom caminho.
Qualquer dúvida complementarei a resposta se possível.